# Thumbnail Issue with Filedialog python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running into an issue with `self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_img)`. It tells me that `AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'`. Am I doing this incorrectly with the thumbnail function?

```
 def fileDialog(self):
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file")
    self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "")
    self.label.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
    self.label.configure(text=os.path.basename(self.filename))

    self.img = Image.open(self.filename)

    self.thumbNail_img = self.img.thumbnail((512, 512))

    self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.thumbNail_img)
    self.display = ttk.Label(image=self.photo)
    self.display.place(relx=0.10, rely=0.10)
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
 File "gui.py", line 44, in fileDialog
self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_img)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 113, in __init__
mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 326, in getmodebase
return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageMode.py", line 56, in getmode
return _modes[mode]
```

Comment: I saw similar question today but previous code had problem with `file=` in `PhotoImage(file=...)` ;)

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas Yes, I was just not aware that thumbnail keeps the aspect ratio of the image. Please see updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
print(type(self.img), type(self.thumbNail_img))
```

and you see

```
<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'> <class 'NoneType'>
```

It means than `self.img` is `Image` but `self.thumbNail_img` is `None`

`thumbnail()` doesn't create new image. It changes original image in `self.img` and returns `None`.
It works `"in-place"`. Doc: [Image.thumbnail](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail)

So you have to use `self.img` to display it

```
 self.img = Image.open(self.filename)

 self.img.thumbnail((512, 512))

 self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
```

---

If you need original image then you can `.copy()` it

```
 self.img = Image.open(self.filename)

 self.thumbNail_img = self.img.copy()

 self.thumbNail_img.thumbnail((512, 512))

 self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.thumbNail_img)
```